# Installing a local SQL database on a FTP server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have created a local SQL database using SQL Server Management Studio. And a program in C# that have a access to that database.
Now I would like to movemy local database to my FTP server. So i could remotely access my database using SSMS and a program that i have created in C#.

My question is, what do i need to do to transfer my database to a FTP server? Is it even possible to have a SQL database on a FTP server, or does it need to be an sql-specific server? Keep in mind that there is no sql managing software installed on a server yet.

Comment: you can run an FTP service and a SQL Server service on the same server at the same time. They are separate unrelated services. A server doesn't have to be dedicated to a single task. However simply copying the database _file_ to the server won't achieve anything. It's just like having a backup file there really. You can't use it unless SQL Server is installed and running on the server. When using SQL server you don't access the _file_ you access the _service_ via a port

Comment: SQL is more than a file. You can ftp that 'database' wherever you like but it'll be just a file unless there's some software to care for it and communicate on a port about it. Install sql server on the ftp server, copy over the database and you're done :)

Comment: @Davesoft Thanks for answer. Do i make a backup in SSMS and copy backup to FTP server, or how can i copy my database?

Comment: yes that would be the normal procedure. Then once SQL Server is running on the new server you connect to the new server via SSMS and restore the database from the backup file. You can find lots of documentation about this procedure in Microsoft's docs and lots of other places online.

Comment: @ADyson So when i have my db set up on a server, i can acces my db from another computer if i type the servers IP in Connection field in SSMS? Thanks, will check that.

Comment: yes as long as there's no firewall blocking the ports etc etc. But that's the general idea. Most databases are held on remote servers rather than people's desktops. It's a very common thing to do.

Comment: Can i import my SQL server database(backup file) in TOAD For MySQL or TOAD For SQL Server? I have Toad For MySQL installed on my server, which is running some web service.

Comment: As long as it can execute a RESTORE statement then yes